# norms of row matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_m,y_1,\ldots,y_m$ be $k\times k$ sqaure matrices and assume $\|x_j\|\leqslant\|y_j\|$ for all $j=1,\ldots,m$ (the norm in $B(\ell_2^k)$). Now define the block matrices $x,y\in M_{mk}$, the first rows of which are $x_j$'s and $y_j$'s, respectively and other rows consist of $k\times k$ zero matrices. Is it true that $\|x\|\leqslant\|y\|$ (the norm in $B(\ell_2^{mk})$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Let 
$$
x_1=x_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ y_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\ \ y_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|=\|y_1\|=\|y_2\|=1$, but
$$
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}x_1& x_2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|
=
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\sqrt2,
$$
while 
$$
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}y_1& y_2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|
=
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=1.
$$
The norms are very easy to calculate because
$$
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|^2
=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A^*&0\\B^*&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|
=\left\|\begin{bmatrix}AA^*+BB^*&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|=\|AA^*+BB^*\|.
$$

Comment: Suppose now that the matrices $x_j,y_j$ are more specific. Namely, let $d$ be a fixed $k\times k$ diagonal matrix with strictly positive numbers on the main diagonal (so $d$ is invertible). Let $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ be any (self-adjoint if one wishes) $k\times k$ matrices and define $x_j:=da_jd$ and $y_j:=d^2a_j$ and block matrices $x,y$ as in the initial question. Do we have the inequality $\|x\|\leqslant\|y\|$ for these specific matrices?